# Scope of @@ variable in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following TSQL code I can use my local variable in first few lines and then I cannot use it again. Why am I not able to use it in the last line of my code ?

Where does its scope end?

```
DECLARE @@CurrentDB varchar(50);
SET @@CurrentDB = 'MyDBNAME';



-- Find Data & Log Fiel locations
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS DatabaseName, name AS LogicalFileName, physical_name AS PhysicalFileName, size/(128*1024) [GB] 
FROM sys.master_files AS mf
WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = @@CurrentDB

-- Detach DB
USE
GO
ALTER DATABASE  SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = @@Cur
GO
```

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: I think you mean to be using [SQLCMD mode - example here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46244/setting-variables-in-sqlcmd-mode). You can't do this with plain T-SQL in Management Studio, at least not with variables.

Comment: You can store the variable in an SSIS package and pass it through to as many execute SQL tasks as your heart desires. If that sort of thing is up your alley.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you pass SQL Server a GO command, that ends the context in which the variable exists and it is no longer accessible by anything after that point in the T-SQL code.  "Global" variables as such do not exist in SQL Server, but there are ways around it, generally by implementing a global variable table (either temporary or permanent).

You can get the general idea from this [blog](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/04/23/60185.aspx) post that sets up a permanent table to track global variables.

Comment: I think you mean global temp table, not global variable table (I don't even know what means).

Comment: I agree. I don't know of a global Variable table and usually stay away from `##TempTables`.

Comment: Thank you its the GO then. So put it in a Table variable and call it from there. Okay. Thanks.

Comment: I meant a permanent table stored somewhere that is globally accessible to all the databases (or just that one) to store "global" variables in.  Thus I called it a global variable table.  It's not an official name for anything.  Just my name for it.  I don't like global temp tables personally.  I try to never use them if I can avoid it.  But that's a whole other debate.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use a [Global Temp Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/vivekssqlnotes/2012/01/07/sql-server-global-temporary-tables/):

```
Declare @CurrentDB varchar(50)
SET @CurrentDB = 'MyDBNAME'
Create Table ##CurrentDB (Name varchar(50))
Insert Into ##CurrentDB Values (@CurrentDB)
GO
-- ...
GO
Declare @CurrentDB varchar(50)
Select Top 1 @CurrentDB = Name From ##CurrentDB 
Select @CurrentDB
```

This should work even if you are using different databases in each part of your script.

Comment: Just be careful, this limits concurrency to exactly 1. Guess what happens when two users try to create that table.

Comment: Also you can do this with a regular `#temp` table, the global is unnecessary.

Comment: Why use a table or variable at all.  This is a simple user defined helper stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

**Why use a global variable or temp table at all?  This cries out to me to be a user defined stored procedure.**

Here are the business rules.

1 - You basically want to get the location and size of a database you want to detach.

2 - Want to set database to single user mode.

3 - You want to detach the database.  Just remember the files will be hanging around afterwards.

I created it in the MSDB database but you can put it in your own toolbox database.

I did not check to see if the database is really in use only mode.  - TODO list

Just check the mode in the sys.databases table.  If the ALTER, fails do not try the detach.  Just notify the user to find the spids and kill them.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx

4 - I did not put any error handling in.  - TODO list

Last but not least, this solution could be prone to SQL injection, do not give the world access.

In short, the stored procedure below does just what you want.

```
--
-- Create a user stored procedure
--

-- Start in msdb
use msdb
go

-- drop existing
if object_id('my_detach_process') > 0
drop procedure my_detach_process
go

-- create new
create procedure my_detach_process(@dbname sysname)
as

  -- Show the data
  SELECT 
    DB_NAME(mf.database_id) AS DatabaseName, 
    mf.name AS LogicalName, 
    mf.physical_name AS PhysicalName, mf.size as SizeMb
  FROM sys.master_files AS mf
  WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = @dbname;

  -- Set to single user
  DECLARE @sqlstmt1 nvarchar(512) = '';
  SET @sqlstmt1 = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @dbname + '] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE';
  EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstmt1;

  -- Detach
  DECLARE @sqlstmt2 nvarchar(512) = '';
  SET @sqlstmt2 = 'USE [master]; EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = ' + @dbname;
  EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstmt2;

GO


--
-- Sample call
--

-- Choose master
use master
go

-- Create toy db
create database toy;
go

-- Call the sp
exec msdb.dbo.my_detach_process @dbname = 'Toy'
```

Sample output from sample call.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I agree. I just changed my mind would create a UD SP.

Comment: But you are using dynamic SQL... You should use `QUOTENAME(@dbname)` in the concatenations.

Comment: @thepirat000 You should really look at the code.  statement One is already placing [] around the name.  Statement Two will fail if you pass a database name with [].  This is a bad suggestion!

Comment: I was just trying to avoid sql injection, sorry

Comment: @thepirat000 Kudos for you thinking about that.  However, DBA related user defined procedures with access only by sysadmins do not need to consider that.  SQL Injection only happens when calls from a WEB front end are blindly passed to the back end.